# How to add HTTP request header in ng2-completer

Tags: typescript, request-headers

I have been struggling for two days now to fix this header issue that I'm having. I am able to call `ng2-completer` API in Postman with no issues.

I need to pass the token in the request header to authenticate. It works fine in Postman, however I tried inside my TypeScript and it does not work at all.

```
 this.dataService = completerService.remote("https://arsapi.azurewebsites.net/api/searchusers?searchstring=", 'userName', 'userName');
   let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: new Headers() });
   options.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
   options.headers.set("Authorization", 'Bearer JeBVR3A');
   this.dataService.requestOptions(options);
```

The above request in TypeScript does not send the header.

Why isn't my request header included in the request?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that the first line of code is making the request, without the headers added?

Comment: Yes it is making call without headers.

Comment: Right, but what I'm asking is this. Is the actual HTTP request made **inside** the `completerService.remote` function, or is it made **after** the `this.dataService.requestOptions(options)` call?

Comment: I have textbox. <ng2-completer [(ngModel)]="searchStr" [datasource]="dataService" [minSearchLength]="0"></ng2-completer> whenever i make type here call will be made to server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what is happening is that you are adding your headers to the request in the code **after** the request is actually made, which is why you are not seeing them in the request.

You need to add these lines inside your `completerService.remote()` function since this is where the actual HTTP request is being made.

```
let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: new Headers() });
options.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
options.headers.set("Authorization", 'Bearer JeBVR3A');
this.dataService.requestOptions(options);
```

I don't know what your `completerService.remote()` function looks like, but whatever line of code is doing the HTTP GET, you will need to put the above lines before this, then pass the `options` variable to it.

Comment: While using typescript, errors may pop up in your editor saying `property does not exist on "CompleterData"`, I had to add `// @ts-ignore` in the previous line to suppress it.

Answer (score 1):

I did this in my component and works:

```
constructor(
    private completerService: CompleterService,
    private authenticationService: AuthenticationService
  ) {
    this.dataService = completerService.remote(`${environment.baseUrl}/cep/autocomplete?term=`, 'label', 'label');
    let options = new RequestOptions({headers: new Headers()});
    options.headers.set('Authorization', authenticationService.getToken());
    options.headers.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    this.dataService.requestOptions(options);
  }
```